# Run script from Android app

Tags: android, bash, shell, permissions

I'm trying to have a script executed from within an app. I use the following to execute the script:

```
try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "sh /data/script.sh" });
        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exceptions", "Exception dropping caches: "+e);
    }
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

Every time I launch the app the script is supposed to be executed.

The script just contains the lines
`#!/system/bin/sh
touch testFile`

The problem though is that the script is not being executed - at least the file `testFile` is not being created. But when I change the code to `{ "su", "-c", "touch /data/testFile" }` it is.

Now, the script is just an example. Eventually I want to execute a different script.
I'm on stock (5.1.1), Nexus 5, rooted.

I already tried different approaches from other threads, and the above code was the only way I could at least create a file using `{ "su", "-c", "touch /data/testFile" }`.

Any ideas, what could be the problem? Do I need another permission maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with the script itself. Try this piece of code instead:

```
{ "su", "-c", "sh /data/script.sh", "2&>1>/sdcard/scripterror.log" }
```

And then check /sdcard/scripterror.log for errors.

Anyway, I suggest you use [this](https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools) library to run commands with su, it's so much easier to use, even I can understand it (and I'm a real beginner in Java)